# Unity create dynamically objects

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I create dynamically objects (cubes) from one wall to the other in code  in Unity? Such here:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's funny that Unity guys have written an example which looks like exactly the same thing you are trying to achieve :)

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html

Comment: Thank you a lot :) Do you know how can I create empty space between cubes?

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate a prefab with 2 for sentences.

```
public GameObject objToCreate;

void Start ()
{
    //2 for sentences to create a vidirectional array
    for(int i = 0; i<5;i++){            //for move on Y
        for(int j = 0; j<5;j++){        //for move on X
            Instantiate(objToCreate, transform.position,transform.rotation);
            transform.Translate(1f,0,0);    //Move on X
        }
        transform.Translate(0,1f,0);    //When fill X translate on Y and start again
        transform.Translate(-5f,0,0);   //Reset out transform position 5 units as set in the first for sentence
        //For mor space between objects just change the values in Translate function
    }
}
```